# Customizing Site Change Password Page - is it possible?

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites

I'm building a customized login page for a customer portal using sites and everything is going great with one exception.  When a user logs back in after a password reset they get directed to the change password page at `/_ui/system/security/ChangePassword`.

The page is displayed using the site template, but the change password form has the sites clock logo, powered by force.com platform logo, along with some other elements I'd like to control.  Has anyone been able to customize this?  Any suggestions for workaround the issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's customizable.  Go to the Sites detail page, click Login Settings.  There is an option to set the ChangePassword page.

Answer (score 1):

Yes correct go to the password change page and write your Vf code .You can also change in the controller if you would like some custom logic.

ChangePasswordController is the apex class

Also dig into Site.changePassword(newPassword, verifyNewPassword, oldpassword) ...

Answer (score 1):

This is incorrect.

No matter what you put in `Login Settings ->  Change Password Page`, it will still take you to:  `/_ui/system/security/ChangePassword`  There has to be a way to customize this, but I havent found one.

This change password page is different from the one you are thinking of where it asks for your old password first.  This one already knows you are logged in.  I created a new stripped down changepassword page and called it changeuserpassword and assigned in in Login Settings and it still redirects to:  `_ui/system/security/ChangePassword`

Comment: the url will be ui/system/security/ChangePassword, but the content will be your custom changeuserpassword page